# Lubuntu 16.04: no audio from tv speakers

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

My Desktop PC is linked to my TV by the following cables:

1. (video + audio) Cable DVI to HDMI High-Speed Dual Link, 24+1 Pin, DVI-D
2. (audio) Cable RCA Jack Adapter Male Audio Stereo (plugged on my machine back jack)

The audio setting in my PC (ubuntu 16.04) shows (among others) the following possibilities:

1. Analog Output
2. Digital Output (S/PDIF)

I have given up with **S/PDIF** (never got to the point to assess whether it is alive).

However **Analog Output** works through the front jack and also works through the back jack, *but the latter happens only if I unplug the DVI to HDMI cable* (therefore loosing the video).

So it seems to me that the audio part of the DVI to HDMI (which doesn't work) prevents the Analog Output from accessing the TV speakers.

My question is: is there a way to give priority to the Analog Audio?

(Please note that this is the default behavior in Windows 7 -my pc is dual boot- where this audio problem doesn't show).

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (from 2016-April thus 16.04) came with 3 years of supported life being a flavor and is now EOL (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-released/ states "*supported until April 2019*"  You mention Ubuntu 16.04 in your text which has 5 years of support (server with no desktop, default Unity 7 desktop, or with Kylin desktop).  'main' packages of 16.04 are still supported, by 'universe' packages aren't for the most part so be aware if using Lubuntu or a 16.04 flavor - part of your system is EOL.

Comment: Hi guiverc, thanks for your comment. I'm aware that the whole Lubuntu 16.04 is approaching EOL, but my pretty old machine doesn't seem to tolerate ver. 18.04 (I tried to install Lubuntu 18.04 but failed)

Comment: Lubuntu 16.04 **is** EOL; **April 2019** is in the past. I tested Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (*& later*) on laptops and desktops as old as 2003 with 1gb of ram, so unless your box is prehistoric, I'd suspect your issues where other than 18.04 (if using 16.04 with HWE you'll be running the kernel & lower stack as 18.04 without HWE anyway).

Comment: yes, sorry to have been inaccurate, what I inarticulately meant to say is that I'm aware that the support will be fading. However I've tried installing lubuntu and ubuntu 18.04 before going back to 16.04 and the installation failed; if this not due to the machine being old then I don't know what caused it. However for my purposes I'm fine with having an old OS. Just need to solve the above issue.